# Import excel file with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, file-upload

I'm working on an asp.net /c# app

I need my app to allow users to upload .XLS files (located on the user machine).

How can i read data from the .XLS file but without saving the file on server?

tks

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to parse .csv files, if it possible. I can send example.
Also you can parse .XLS files through interop excel dll. But it very slow method.

Comment: Could you send example, please? tks

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to do something with the file on the server (eg using ASP.net ) you will have to at least temporarily save the file on the server.  Although an apache module might let you interupt the stream as it is uploaded, but thats probably a bit ott.

There MAY be something you could do in Javascript but I doubt it.